# How to convert a list or numpy array to a 1d torch tensor?

Tags: pytorch

I have a list (or, a numpy array) of float values. I want to create a 1d torch tensor that will contain all those values. I can create the torch tensor and run a loop to store the values.

But I want to know is there any way, I can create a torch tensor with initial values from a list or array? Also suggest me if there is any pythonic way to achieve this as I am working in pytorch.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These are general operations in pytorch and available in the documentation. PyTorch allows easy interfacing with numpy. There is a method called `from_numpy` and the documentation is available [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/torch.html?highlight=from_numpy#torch.from_numpy)

```python
import numpy as np 
import torch 
array = np.arange(1, 11)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(array)
```